# php artisan serve not working giving error In ProviderRepository.php line 208:Class 'Laravelium\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm working for the first time in laravel while setting up the already developed project in my local computer and running `php artisan serve` i'm getting this error

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Laravelium\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug that problem?

Comment: i have tried ```composer dump-autoload``` and ```php artisan cache:clear``` but that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is resolved by just follow these step. Go to your project > bootstrap->cache->config.php remove the provider and aliases from the cached array manually.

Comment: hey bro there is no file named as config.php in bootstrap->cache folder

Comment: packages.php file is there in the folder